# Edx-platform illegal characters appearing on assets

Tags: edx, openedx

I am using my fork of edx-platform in my devstack instance. I encounter an error many times where illegal characters appear on the home page:
[image: A screenshot of edx-platform homepage]

I have posted this question to the edx mailing group but they said it was because of the changes I made to the code. But I cannot agree with them. Because if I checkout previous states of my fork, the bug is still there. And as you can see in the console, it's i18n.js which I never modified. I don't even know it existed until now.

And if I click sign in, it cannot load the rest of the page because of the errors in the console:
[image: Sign in view screenshot]

Even recreating the vagrant instance, the bug still persists.
I'm posting here because the mailing list doesn't seem to know how to solve this.

Comment: have you tried restarting your lms and studio with paver ?

Comment: If by restarting you mean ctrl-c and running paver devstack lms again, Yes I did many times. As I mentioned I even recreated the vm.

Comment: what is the output of `paver update_assets lms --settings=devstack` ?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to capture the text of i18n.js and show us what it is.  That will help track down the problem.

Comment: Also, I can't find the message on the mailing list.  That would be a better place to discuss this.

Comment: This is the link to the message in the mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openedx-ops/9YpT8ASFc3s Yes I know it's better to discuss it there but they won't offer me solution for this.

Comment: @frank this is the output when I run paver update_assets lms --settings=devstack: http://pastebin.com/nTrhHKDH

Comment: @user3631341, could you show us the i18n.js file ?

Comment: Here is the code of i18.js file: http://pastebin.com/zrnU3qaK As you will see, there is an 8b2 character at the top and a zero at the bottom.

Comment: i18n.js file is generated by django, check your django.views.i18n.py file, may be you can find something.